# Vega-lite heat map change the color, location, test

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, heatmap, vega, vega-lite

Good time of day!

formerly = [Vega-lite heat map text properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405646/vega-lite-heat-map-text-properties)

1)How to build a new X2-axis in this scheme, which takes into account the original X-axis

{"window": [{"op": "count", "field": "x", "as": "x2"}], "groupby": ["y"]}

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.4.3.json",
      "config": {"view": {"height": 300, "width": 400}},
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": "X1", "y": "Y1", "z": 1,"Name":"Name3"}
          {"x": "X3", "y": "Y1", "z": 9,"Name":"Name2"}
          {"x": "X3", "y": "Y1", "z": 25,"Name":"Name1"}
          {"x": "X0", "y": "Y2", "z": 1,"Name":"Name1"}
          {"x": "X1", "y": "Y2", "z": 2,"Name":"Name1"}
          {"x": "X4", "y": "Y2", "z": 20,"Name":"Name1"}
          {"x": "X5", "y": "Y2", "z": 40,"Name":"Name1"}
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"window": [{"op": "count", "field": "x", "as": "x2"}], "groupby": ["y"]}
        {"window": [{"op": "count", "field": "Name", "as": "x7"}], "groupby": ["x","y"]}
        {
          "calculate": "'https://google.com/search?q='+datum.y",
          "as": "web"
        }
      ],

      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x2", "type": "ordinal", "title": "X"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Y"}
      },


      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "rect",
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "z",
              "scale": {"scheme": "redyellowgreen"},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          "tooltip": [
            {"field": "x", "type": "ordinal", title: "text"}
            {"field": "y", "type": "ordinal", title: "text1"}
            {"field": "z", "type": "ordinal", title: "text2"}
          ]
          "href": {"field": "web"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 10, "dy": -20},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "x"},
            "color": {"value": "black"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 20, "dy": 40},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "x7"},
            "color": {"value": "black"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 20, "dy": 20},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "z", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"value": "black"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

[image]

2)how to make clear color boundaries? like here:
[image]
I use it:

```
"color": {"aggregate": "average","field": "z", "type": "quantitative","format": ".0f", "scale": {   "domain": [0,20,25,35],"range": ["#6ce165", "#E0ED15", "#ED9715", "#CE4334"]}}
```

3) how to add text here:

```
    {
  "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 20, "dy": 40},
  "encoding": {
    "text": {"field": "x7"},+ Text????
    "color": {"value": "black"}
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Please only ask one question per post. I do not understand what you are asking in the first or third part of your question, so I will answer the second.

You can make the color scale discrete using a binned encoding:

```
"encoding": {
  "color": {
    "field": "z",
    "scale": {"scheme": "redyellowgreen"},
    "type": "ordinal",
    "bin": true
  }
}
```

Here is the result ([Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAmOgBY6AZjoArWNwB2kADTgo8TQDNG1bGGCQKjZAHczFlCfxnFABlfaoNxgBMWZuXcAXyDdCEgfdDxMHFAIcIp0MVZkWDMAbT1480gADzMPKABPAs9IAC8C0Kz4i3ycAEYykpxCirMG6uyIOrNpZtKoSpw5Lu7ekYHWsuGwBoA2MeyJsDaWuZmOpdq8jqmNob7tnt2cfuK9w5wAVmOc+rBFfaarudc7levnzbPFmoBdPRjSB4ABO6A0sEM3FBqAyNQs3g0Pm4dhw6Qs3EIZkgBlYGjwOigxmQYh8OPyZXQaRweWkkCC-zK1FB3FYhHY63SkBK-yCeiZekgyA0Bh8jA0pliNVOORJZIp9LKeCKhGQOJh4o0SSJIOYYnVtIAGgywvEefZIPLybSSsrVYaoJqJTrlfrHZAAJoMoFmyBidBFZCg+HLGrhDCggDWONByHghLN2WFou4Wql5nD5oMYhh9izyetOMqSe64QQSUdFn4aA9cZ8QbEuZsLOQItNBfNKrVGtBWtdnfC7AlZjBKU7-LLk-i2zi3UgkZjsRBDpxeGQuUTxM0eAAyoxyo7pG0G2YRMe7imxRKM3OyyCN4Tl4lkh715uO2Xwjm88+kikcXYAN4BjadsjAsBZyzBd0GjS1uzfR9dWhAl90PAIT3WC9S3CEVr0lfMvygd8nzlawFVpEtiNXWkAEdWAhPBmCiRgqE-L9cW4XMQz-V9AOA0Cswg6dASCIA)):
[image]